# AWS implementation issue on AWSMobileHubHelper.framework

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have searched the web for a possible solution, but without any luck.
Currently i'm trying to integrate the default AWS frameworks into my project. But i can't get rid of the following errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSGetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSubscribeInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSGoogleSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNS", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKGraphRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSUnsubscribeInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_AWSSNSErrorDomain", referenced from:
      ___88-[AWSPushManager interceptApplication:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke.239 in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tryed removing "-ObjC" from "Other linker flags", without luck.
Because these frameworks aren't the only frameworks i use, not all solutions work for me. Simply removing 'ARM64' is no solution.

Please help.